# Persistent file on USB

Tags: usb-drive, persistence

I've created a persistent file (4GB) on the USB drive I boot off of. Correct me if I'm wrong but will creating this persistent file, allow changes in the Ubuntu environment?

If so, after each reboot, I lose all file changes and applications installed which defeats the purpose of a persistent file. If not, please explain what a persistent file is and what it's used for?

Comment: How did you create the USB drive?

Comment: I used pendrivelinux. I've tried 2 different usb drives. One being a flash drive (fat32) and an external (exFAT). It looks as if the program automatically formats the partition though so maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: Is there space on the USB a (separate partition) to save files?

Comment: Yes. As far as saving files that's not really the issue because of the separate partition. For instance I'm using wine to run an audio program. I installed it yesterday and when I booted today neither the program nor wine was there. Is the OS being booted off a usb not intended to run in this manner? I would have no problem just installing the OS to the hard drive but it's my family computer and they can't seem to comprehend selecting windows (which I refuse to use) off the boot menu.

Comment: What size is your USB drive?

Comment: The flash drive is 4GB with a 1GB persistent and my external is 500GB with a 4GB persistent but is partitioned half FAT 32 and half exFat. Ubuntu is installed on the exFat partition. I have the same problem on both the flash and external.

Comment: IS there a syslinux.cfg file on the USB, if yes, contents of that file.

Comment: "# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50

# If you would like to use the new menu and be presented with the option to install or run from USB at startup, remove # from the following line. This line was commented out (by request of many) to allow the old menu to be presented and to enable booting straight into the Live Environment! 
# ui gfxboot bootlogo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short.  Persistence is the space on your USB key the will be used to store information, so that that information is still there after a reboot.

Confirm that your `syslinux.cfg`, has the word persistence in it.
If not you can add it after the first --.
Code:

```
-- persistence
```

For more information click [Here](http://rusteddev.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/persistent-ubuntu-live-usb-keep-your-config-after-boot/)